# Parallax no rodapé

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

```css
html {
  font-family: Gabriola;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#titulo-fotos {
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.linha-galeria {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.textoo {
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.botao-parceria input[type="submit"],
.btn-parceria {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-left: 190%; */
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.botao-parceria input[type="submit"]:hover,
.btn-parceria {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#parceria {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  top: 20px;
  left: 28%;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
#parceria ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#parceria ul li a img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#parceria ul li a img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
#fundo-transparente-parcerias {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15%;
  top: 235%;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  z-index: -200;
}
.icones-parceiros {
  width: 100%;
}
.main-teste {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 0 400px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
#main-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content-teste {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.teste-footer {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Nova Era Team</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>



  <div class="container testee-geral icones-parceiros main-teste">
    <div class="content-teste">
      <header class="major">
        <h2 id="titulo-fotos">Nossos Parceiros</h2>
      </header>
      <p class="textoo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque.
        <br>Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus.
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr class="linha-galeria">
        <br>
        <img src="images/logo-transp.png" id="fundo-transparente-parcerias">
        <section class="wow fadeInDown">
          <nav id="parceria">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/lvlup.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/gamehall.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/gamevicio.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/triplex.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/centralkeys.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/gametalk.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </section>
    </div>

    <center>
      <div class="botao-parceria">
        <input type="submit" value="Mais sobre eles..." class="btn-parceria">
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <footer id="main-footer">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="teste-footer">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero officia beatae praesentium accusamus, delectus possimus ea eligendi minima, laudantium amet corrupti quas quae sint sunt, a iure. Quaerat, recusandae, voluptatibus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

estou com um problema com meu *parallax* gostaria de colocar o mesmo em meu rodapé porém não estou conseguindo queria um efeito parecido com o desse site:

http://www.fatemi.com.br/home/parallax-cidades/

já utilizei *Parallax* no restante da minha pagina porem não estou conseguindo no rodapé.

OBS: não e possível eu postar toda a minha estrutura no *jsfidle* pois e muito grande meu projeto mais só de simular algo do tipo conseguirei colocar em meu site.

Comment: Consegue colocar no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) pra ajudar o pessoal..?

Comment: entao eu nunca usei ele mais posso colocar so que o site e grande e tambem depende dos meus arquivos javascripts para funcionar seria possivel ainda sim ultilizar

Comment: Kirito, bem-vindo ao site. Para as próximas perguntas, dê uma olhada [nesta página de ajuda](/help/mcve). O ideal é tentar reduzir os exemplos que você posta ao mínimo que reproduza o problema.

Comment: ola amigo editei o meu post agora creio eu que ficou mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é tão complicado criar esse tipo de efeito, o segredo está em usar a propriedade `z-index` do CSS, então você vai colocar o seu conteúdo com a margem inferior com o mesmo valor da altura do seu rodapé, e irá fixar o rodapé no `bottom` da janela.

```css
html {
  font-family: Gabriola;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
#titulo-fotos {
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.linha-galeria {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.textoo {
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.botao-parceria input[type="submit"],
.btn-parceria {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-left: 190%; */
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.botao-parceria input[type="submit"]:hover,
.btn-parceria {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#parceria {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  top: 20px;
  left: 28%;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
#parceria ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#parceria ul li a img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#parceria ul li a img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
#fundo-transparente-parcerias {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15%;
  top: 235%;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  z-index: -200;
}
.icones-parceiros {
  width: 100%;
}
#main-teste {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 0 400px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
#main-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content-teste {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.teste-footer {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-teste">
  <div class="content-teste">
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  <p>conteudo-teste</p>
  </div>


  <div class="container testee-geral icones-parceiros main-teste">
    <div class="content-teste">
      <header class="major">
        <h2 id="titulo-fotos">Nossos Parceiros</h2>
      </header>
      <p class="textoo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque.
        <br>Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus.
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr class="linha-galeria">
        <br>
        <img src="images/logo-transp.png" id="fundo-transparente-parcerias">
        <section class="wow fadeInDown">
          <nav id="parceria">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/lvlup.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/gamehall.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/gamevicio.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/triplex.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/centralkeys.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <img src="images/parceiros/gametalk.png" alt="" />
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </section>
    </div>

    <center>
      <div class="botao-parceria">
        <input type="submit" value="Mais sobre eles..." class="btn-parceria">
      </div>
    </center>
    <br><br>
  </div>
</div>
  <footer id="main-footer">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="teste-footer">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero officia beatae praesentium accusamus, delectus possimus ea eligendi minima, laudantium amet corrupti quas quae sint sunt, a iure. Quaerat, recusandae, voluptatibus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

### [JSLink](https://jsfiddle.net/6e98o74d/)

---

Fique bem atento nas propriedades `position`, pois é ali que combinado com o `z-index` a história é desenrolada.

Comment: "hmm" amigo irei testar isso agora mesmo

Comment: amigo testei e não deu certo eu editei meu post e coloquei somente um trecho do meu código onde insiro o seu código e testo veja oque acontece não sei porque acontece isso ele fixa o rodapé porem ele continua aparecendo mesmo se eu colocar um z-index:-99999;

Comment: @Kirito, você tem que separar todo o conteúdo do site do rodapé, você deixou solto ali, onde está a div com o id `#main-teste`?

Comment: @Kirito, editei a resposta repare que as `div`s `#main-teste` e `.content-teste` está separando o conteúdo do site do _footer_. O segredo não é o `z-index` do _footer_ e sim o do `#main-teste`.

Comment: muito obrigado amigo me ajudou de mais

Comment: ola amigo se lembra de min sou eu de novo "rs" acabei de abrir um post novamente com esse problema que tive com o rodapé só que  em outra pagina que to desenvolvendo porem olhei novamente a sua resposta e ela não esta funcionando nessa pagina sera que você poderia dar uma olhadinha :            http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62760/rodap%C3%A9-n%C3%A3o-fica-escondido-com-o-conte%C3%BAdo-da-p%C3%A1gina